# Is every space group the symmetry group of some triply periodic minimal surface?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, crystals, minimal-surfaces

I know that there are a lot of TPMS with different symmetry groups.  It seems like every space group is the symmetry group of some TPMS.  But I can not find a reference that confirms this for all the 230 space groups.  If this is not true, what are (possible) counter-examples?